# Javascript add number to views

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-template

So I am looking to modify this javascript.

The script says : Limited stock!  7 people are viewing this.

"7" being the number of views in the code. However, I am looking to add +8 to that number so it looks like I have more views. 
I have no idea how to add that +8 to the number of views.

Here is the code:

```
<span class="banana-statement">
  <span class="banana-qty-sentence">
    {% if options.show_only_x_left and counts.stock < options.only_left_threshold %}
      <span class="banana-only-x-left">Only <span class="banana-stock-qty">{{ counts.stock }}</span> left!</span>
    {% else %}
      <span class="banana-default-stock-msg">{{ options.default_stock_message }}</span>
    {% endif %}
  </span>
  {% if counts.views >= options.min_view_count_to_show %}
    <span class="banana-views-sentence banana-sentence {% if counts.views > 1 %}multiple-bananas{% endif %}">
      <span class="banana-count">{{ counts.views + 5}}</span>
      {% if counts.views > 1 %}people are{% else %}person is{% endif %}
      viewing this{% if counts.orders >= options.min_order_count_to_show and counts.carts >= options.min_cart_count_to_show %},{% elsif counts.orders < options.min_order_count_to_show and counts.carts < options.min_cart_count_to_show %}.{% else %} and{% endif %}
    </span>
  {% endif %}
  {% if counts.orders >= options.min_order_count_to_show %}
    <span class="banana-orders-sentence banana-sentence {% if counts.orders > 1 %}multiple-bananas{% endif %}">
      <span class="banana-count">{{ counts.orders }}</span>
      {% if counts.views < options.min_view_count_to_show %}{% if counts.orders > 1 %}people{% else %}person{% endif %}{% endif %} recently purchased {% if counts.views < options.min_view_count_to_show %}this{% else %}it{% endif %}{% if counts.carts < options.min_cart_count_to_show %}.{% else %} and {% endif %}
    </span>
  {% endif %}
  {% if counts.carts >= options.min_cart_count_to_show %}
    <span class="banana-carts-sentence banana-sentence {% if counts.carts > 1 %}multiple-bananas{% endif %}">
      <span class="banana-count">{{ counts.carts }}</span>
      {% if counts.orders < options.min_order_count_to_show %}{% if counts.carts > 1 %}people{% else %}person{% endif %}{% endif %}{% if counts.carts > 1 %} have {% if counts.orders < options.min_order_count_to_show and counts.views < options.min_view_count_to_show %}this{% else %}it{% endif %}{% else %} has this{% endif %} in their cart.
    </span>
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: Please don't flag javascript questions with the java tag. They aren't remotely the same thing.

Comment: change this {{ counts.views + 5}} with whatever number you want

Answer (score 1):

In order to add within liquid, you have to use the [plus filter](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/plus/).

So basically, you just need to change `{{ counts.views + 5}}` to `{{ counts.views | plus: 5}}`